# "- (void)splitViewController willHideViewController withBarButtonItem forPopoverController" not called

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an application that has following schema:

> Login -> Tab Bar ->
>
> 1. UINavigationController -> Tab1ViewController
> 2. UISplitViewController -> UINavigationController -> MasterViewController/DetailViewController
> 3. UINavigationController -> Tab3ViewController

Then I implement in my DetailViewController

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
```

but it never get called.

I also have put the splitview delegate in my detail:

```
@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController
<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing multiple things.

One, in order to quickly solve your problem, write:

```
splitViewController.delegate = self;
```

Two, note that it does not matter whether or not you're conforming to the `<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>` protocol. It's just a hint for the compiler - it does not make the view controller magically know which object is supposed to be its delegate...

Three, as a sidenote: this has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: @H2CO3 I have spent (too) many hours on this problem, but I simply cannot see how your solution can solve the problem of willHideViewController: not being called. Where do you propose that we write "splitViewController.delegate = self;"?

Comment: Finally found the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855639/uisplitviewcontroller-not-showing-popup-button-when-launching-portrait: you have to put splitViewController.delegate = self; in DetailViewController's  awakeFromNib.